# Discrete mathematics, sets, increasing functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this assignment where I'm really lost and not sure how to solve. The assignment follows:

> We have two sets, $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. We
>   say that a function $F$ is growing if $x \le y$ or $F(x)\le F(y)$. How
>   many growing functions are there from $A$ to $X$?

I would appreciate advice on how to start and what to do next.

I have figured out that there are 6^7 functions from $A$ to $X$, and I know that the $(n+1)^{th}$ element need to be equal or bigger than the $n^{th}$ element, meaning $n+1\ge n$, for all increasing function, so it should look a little something like this, these below are some of the growing functions.

[a,a,a,a,a,a,a]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,b]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,c]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,d]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,e]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,b]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,c]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,d]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,e]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,c,c]
[a,a,a,a,a,c,d]
[a,a,a,a,a,c,e]
[a,a,a,a,a,c,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,d,d]
[a,a,a,a,a,d,e]
[a,a,a,a,a,d,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,e,e]
[a,a,a,a,a,e,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,f,f]
[a,a,a,a,b,b,b]
[a,a,a,a,b,b,c]
[a,a,a,a,b,b,e]

Now I don't know how to create a formula or how to prove and calculate how many increasing functions there are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A function is growing if $x\leq y$ **THEN** $F(x)\leq F(y)$.  Not "**or**."

Comment: I assume you meant $6^7$, not 67.

Notice if f(x) = a for all x not the last, you 7 choices for f(7).  if f(x) = a, x < 7 - 1 and f(7-1) = b, you have 7-2 choices for f(7) and so on.

Comment: Yes, I mean 6^7

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** These functions are in direct bijection with sequences of 5 stars and 7 bars.  Equivalently these can be seen as lattice paths which use only ups and rights starting from (0,a) going to (7,f).

The function $[a,a,b,c,e,f,f]$ for example corresponds to the sequence $--\star-\star -\star\star-\star--$ and the lattice path

[image]

The function $[a,a,a,a,b,b,b]$ for example corresponds to the sequence $----\star ---\star\star\star\star$ and the lattice path

[image]

The function $[c,c,c,c,c,c,c]$ corresponds to the sequence $\star\star-------\star\star\star$

[image]

See if you can come up with the specific rules for the bijection yourself.  How many sequences of stars and bars described above exist?

Comment: Sorry, don't want to seem to stupid, but I don't really get it..

Comment: @mathematician31415 Let each bar represent one of the numbers.  Count how many stars are to the left of the bar.  The number of stars to the left correspond to the letter.  Do you see why each increasing function can be represented as exactly one sequence and why each sequence represents exactly one increasing function?

Comment: Equivalently, these could be seen as lattice paths which use only rights and ups which start from the point (0,a) and go until (7,f).  Perhaps that would be a more visual explanation of what is going on.

Comment: I have a really hard time getting my mind around this. Any further explanations would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see why the sequences of stars and bars are the same as the lattice paths (think of dashes as rights and stars as ups).  Do you see why the lattice paths are the same as the increasing functions?  (think of where the path first crosses the respective lines)  Do you know how to count how many permutations there are of the multiset "UUUUURRRRRR"?

Comment: ah ok, now I think I get it, so we basically have to cross diagonally, and the stars and lines explain what path we take.  From here I don't know where to go mathematically to prove it, and I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Thanks.

Comment: @mathematician31415 there is a common question asked in a first course in combinatorics of "How many ways are there to rearrange the letters of BABA"  (AABB, ABAB, ABBA, BAAB, BABA, BBAA).  Here, we are choosing where the ups go and where the rights go.  Since we know that there are just as many monotonic functions as there are lattice paths, and just as many lattice paths as there are sequences of stars and bars, and we know how to count the number of sequences of stars and bars, we therefore also know how to count the number of monotonic functions.

Comment: ahhh okay I think I get it, so we got in total 7 lines, and 5 stars, a total of 12 element, which can be sorted in 12! ways, but since all the stars and all the lines are identical (like 2 of the letter A i.e), we have to take 12!/(5!*7!), right?

Comment: That is the idea.  Often times in counting problems like these, if the original question is worded in a way that you aren't sure how to count, a good strategy is to try to find a bijection from it (like we did here) to something that you *do* know how to count.  To be formal, you should also explain *why* the two counting problems are in bijection.

Comment: Big thanks! You just made my night.

Comment: Just one more question, you said that we start in (0,0) and go to (7,f), don't we start in (1,a)?

Comment: @mathematician31415 (0,a) I meant as opposed to (0,0).  We don't start in (1,a) because the way the bijection I'm thinking of as it is worded would not work.  The bijection I suggest is looking at the first time it crosses the line.  Since $f(1)$ can be something *other* than a, we need to give it enough space to have a chance to change, hence the addition of the zeroth spot in the picture.